# "IllegalStateException Fragment not attached to Activity" when restarting the app

Tags: android, fragment, illegalstateexception

I have a strange problem with one `Fragment` of my `ViewPager`. I have a `ViewPager` with three `Fragment`.
Everything was running ok till now. when app starts, the `ViewPager` (with `FragmentPagerAdapter`) attached the three fragments so I could navigate swiping from one to another without any problem.
the problem came when I tried to restart the app manually (after logging out) like that:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Now when I logout and app restart application crash and through an `IllegalStateException Fragment not attached to Activity` when trying to access to resources from on of the fragments.

Here is the code where I attach `fragments`, the `adapter`:

```
public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public BaseListFragment getItem(int index) {

            switch (index) {
            case 0:
            case R.id.index_explore:


                BaseListFragment fragment0 = new Fragment0();
                fragment0.setUserVisibleHint(true);

                return fragment0;

            case 1:
            case R.id.index_main:

                if (fragment instanceof FragmentList)
                    ((FragmentList) fragment).removeMap();
                return new Fragment1();

            case 2:
            case R.id.index_my_stuff:

                BaseListFragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
                fragment2.setUserVisibleHint(true);
                return fragment2;

            default:

                if (fragment instanceof FragmentList)
                    ((FragmentList) fragment).removeMap();

                return new Fragment1();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

    }
```

Then, I set the `adpater`:

```
mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

It is Fragment0 which cause the crash.
I don't understand why it happens, since it should re-build everything (so the adapter with fragments too) like it does when application starts for the first time.
Maybe there is something that I am assuming that is not correct?
I have previously search for some similar question, and there are a lot related with this exception, but don't resolve my case, which I think is a particular one.

Comment: Post the activity code where you have added the fragments

Comment: I've just edited my question. Hope it helps. Thanks. I was thinking that the problem was with restarting, since it works perfectly till this moment. Maybe the way I restart the app doesn't re-create the activity so, it doesn't attach the fragment but use a saved instance that has already detach them? I don't know if I'm explaining it well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10941410/1865860 maybe is useful

Comment: @dentex, I already saw it, but I don't know how it could help me. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I already solved. As I supposed, my problem was the way I was "restarting" the app. It seems like it didn't re-created MainActivity again, so it didn't re-build and attach all `fragments`.
Now I `restart` in another way, a solution that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294428/how-to-restart-an-application-completely)

Is that correct to use `Alarmmanager` for this purpose?
This is the code I used:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, new Intent(getIntent()), getIntent().getFlags());
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), intent);
System.exit(2);
```