# Restarting Android app programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Force application to restart on first activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470870/force-application-to-restart-on-first-activity)

I am trying to restart my application from a fragment like that:

```
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Restarting app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i = getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    getActivity().finish();
```

The code does nothing. The `finish()` is the only thing working for some reason. If I remove the `finish()`, nothing happens. Why is that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294428/how-to-restart-an-application-completely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically "restart" an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/how-do-i-programmatically-restart-an-android-app)

Comment: Where are you executing this code? Is this in an `Activity`? If so, which one? Please post your manifest. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have you looked into **finishAffinity**?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you just consider to switch to your starting `Activity`, refer to [**Ricardo's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071063/6144793) answer. But this approach won't reset static context of your app and won't rebuild the `Application` class, so the app won't be really restarted.

If you want to completely restart your app, I can advise more radical way, using `PendingIntent`.

```
private void restartApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourStarterActivity.class);
    int mPendingIntentId = MAGICAL_NUMBER;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), mPendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

**P.S.** Tried your code in my project - works well with and without `finish()`. So maybe you have something specific about your Activity or Fragment, you haven't written.

Comment: You should consider using **android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());** as well

Comment: This solution works well with 1 problem. Normally our application exits if the android back button pressed from the main activity. However with thie solution I need to press the back button so many times as many time the application was restarted. Any idea?

Comment: it is not working in Android Q. Can you update the answer? found this https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts article but couldn't found a solution.

Comment: I confirm, this solution works on Android 9 but does not work on Android 10 (Android Q). I tested on a Pixel XL 4 with no luck... except this way: If I launch the app from the "App Info" page using the "Open" button, then it works, respawning the app as expected! ...but that's a very specific use case! :P

Answer (score 27):

This works with Android > 10, tested up to Android 13 (preview)

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(ctx.getPackageName());
Intent mainIntent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(intent.getComponent());
ctx.startActivity(mainIntent);
Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
```

Comment: This is beautifully simple and works well in my tests on Android-12.

Comment: It's perfect and works very smoothly. I suggest everyone to use this method. I tested in android 7 it works well.

Comment: Works in Android 14 (API 34)

Answer (score 8):

Please refer below code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourHomeActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    this.finishAffinity();
```

It is starting your home activity and dismiss all other activities. It looks like a restart to users, but the process is the same.

Answer (score 6):

try this one

```
 Intent intent = getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Why do you have these two specific intent flags?

Comment: Be careful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035328/why-calling-process-killprocessprocess-mypid-is-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 4):

Tray this

```
getActivity().finish();
getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Main.class));
getActivity().finishAffinity();
```

where `finishAffinity()` close all other Intents

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
             .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

You can refer to [previous discussion (click here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564614/how-to-restart-an-android-application-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

As the accepted answer doesn't seem to work on Android Q anymore due to the new background launch limitations, let me add my own solution:

```
startActivity(
    Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
)
System.exit(0)
```

Although it looks strange, it works very reliably for me, as the intent takes longer to fire than the system exit does. Plus, it is fired from the main thread, so Android Q won't complain.

Answer (score 2):

Once you add this `FLAGS`to the intent

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and call `startActivity()`, it will clear all the other activities including the one you call this from, so calling `finish()` after `startActivity()` will close the started activity.

Basically, remove `getActivity().finish()`.

Comment: I specifically wrote in the question: "If I remove the finish(), nothing happens."

Answer (score 1):

This works for me 'Activity.recreate()'

```
activity?.recreate()
```

Comment: This method does not result in restarting the application. This simply recreates the activity (the same as configuration change). If the application is not top task activity - you will be left with plenty of elements in the history.

Comment: This solution was perfect for me. I had some lateinet variable in my activity and it was crashes. I had problem with a webView load but recreate() (kotlin) solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

try using below lines:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(YourCurrentActivity.this);
```

ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(YourCurrentActivity.this); this line clear the instance after creating another activity

Comment: The method finishAfterTransition(Activity) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat

Answer (score 0):

Add this code as per your activity and your app will restart. This code is in kotlin.

```
val intent = Intent(baseContext, MainActivity::class.java)
val pendingIntentId = 101
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, pendingIntentId,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
val alarmManager = (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)) as AlarmManager
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pendingIntent)
exitProcess(0)
```

Comment: Since Android 10 you can't launch from background, use my method below. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts