# How to programmatically restart an app in Android 10?

Tags: java, android

I want a way to restart an app after the user has made any in-app purchase that removes ad banners, so that the `onCreate()` methods gets called again.

The problem is, I don’t want any services to be killed, I just want the app to restart with changed restrictions

I found this code on Stack Overflow:

```java
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: If you accept answer, please check it to close

Comment: Since Android 10 you can't launch from background. use my method below. Use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71392776/2603965

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restarting Android app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070938/restarting-android-app-programmatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: To restart your application, Make your Root Activity's Intent, while setting these flags

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

This will ensure a fresh instance of your root activity is launched (the first flag), while all previous activities are popped off the stack (the second flag)

---

<strike>Use [`recreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate()) when inside the same activity.</strike>

If your app is not running, it's already refreshed on opening anyways.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't restart the whole app, it just restarts the activity. What if the user then goes back to the previous activity, its state would still be the same as when there was no purchase made, meaning banner ads would still be there.

Comment: Yes. In that case, use an Intent as mentioned in @Francesco's solution, while adding the flags as mentioned in the updated answer.

Comment: Now I only have one more problem, who do I give Accepted answer to? :)

Comment: Yes, the second flag does that.

Comment: Whose to accept is up to you, but I believe I've answered the actual/critical part of the question.

Comment: Convincing argument :)

Comment: it also works in android 11

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Intent refresh= new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(refresh);
```

Comment: This is great but is there a way to make it wait 1 or two seconds before it restarts? I want the app to have finished writing a boolean to sharedpreferences before it starts again (the boolean is to state that a purchase was made)

Comment: if you put this code after sharedpreferences, it will wait that all is finish (is usless "wait 1 or 2 seconds")

Comment: Hi are you certain that editor.apply() will always finish before the code under it?

Comment: You can check if editor.apply() was successful. But using timer is not a good idea

Comment: Also what if the user returns to a previous activity after restarting this one? The previous activity is still using the state that it was created in earlier, meaning it still has the ad banner. Isn't better to restart the whole app rather than just the activity the user is currently in?

Comment: This is not good solution man.. Where is your flags? This code keep activities in ram..

Comment: This worked great for me, though it doesn't restart the app, just the activity. 
Note for future readers, getActivity doesn't work in Activities (according to s.o on SF), use getApplicationContext instead.