# How to restart android app programmatically

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to re-start my app through Pending intent. Below code is not working.

```
val intent = Intent(this, Activity::class.java).apply {
     flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
}
val pendingIntentId = 1
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
val mgr = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
val timeToStart = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000L
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timeToStart, pendingIntent)
exitProcess(0)
```

Target version is 31, so updated pending intent with `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` still not working. I searched in many links related to this but no luck.

[Restarting Android app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070938/restarting-android-app-programmatically)

[Force application to restart on first activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470870/force-application-to-restart-on-first-activity)

[https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/restart-application-programmatically-android-with-code-examples/#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20programmatically%20restart,finishes%20and%20automatically%20relaunches%20us.%20%7D](https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/restart-application-programmatically-android-with-code-examples/#:%7E:text=How%20do%20I%20programmatically%20restart,finishes%20and%20automatically%20relaunches%20us.%20%7D)

In Nov 2022, When target version is 31 & min sdk version is 29, above pending intent code is not restarting the App.

Any clue why above pending intent is not working or any other suggestion apart from re-launching the activity ?? I don't want to re-launch using `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: Try `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)` or `System.exit(0)`

Comment: It might helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/how-do-i-programmatically-restart-an-android-app

Comment: Check it out as well its Android 12 compatible https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix

Comment: It is compulsory to use pending intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to resteart the entire app you could use the very easy libary: [ProcessPhoenix](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix)

You can just simply insert the Library and execute:

```
ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(context);
```

or with a specific intent:

```
Intent nextIntent = //...
ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(context, nextIntent);
```

This is the easiest way to restart an android app programatically.